# Prysm and private network

Tags: go-ethereum, bootnodes, prysm

I want to make a private network through the documentation say that you have to install prysm or an other consensus client in order to run the network. Through further digging consensus clients are meant to be for eth2 and it is not mandatory for eth1. Further more  through the documentation on private-network section doesn't mention of installing a consensus client but a bootnode. Also at Prysm documentation the networks that is ment to be connected is at MainNet Sepolia and Goerli. Please can someone explain to me if i have to use a consensus client on a private network or a bootnode is just enough?

Answer (score 1):

apparently prysm and geth are two separate clients for separate eth versions. prysm -> eth2 and geth-> eth1 you DONT need to have prysm in order to run geth